# How to attach a progress bar (e.g. tqdm) to f.write()?

Tags: python, file-io, progress-bar, file-writing, tqdm

```py
with open("./output/" + filename + ".txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(very_long_string)
```

I have a very long string that I have to write to file, and I would like to attach a progress bar to the write process. How could I hook the progress bar to the write process?

I've looked at a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213006/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-progress-bar-such-as-tqdm-to-pyyaml-yaml-load-functi) (?) and attempted this, but it doesn't quite work:

```py
class tqdmIOWrapper(io.TextIOBase):
    def __init__(self, file, callback):
        self.file = file
        self.callback = callback

    def write(self, string):
        buf = self.file.write(string)
        if buf:
            self.callback(buf)
        return buf

with open("./output/" + filename + ".js", "w") as f:
    f.write("var " + filename + " = ")
    with tqdm(
        total=len(very_long_string), desc="Printing: " + filename, mininterval=1
    ) as pbar:
        wrapper = tqdmIOWrapper(f, pbar.update)
        wrapper.write(very_long_string)
        pbar.update()
```

The progress bar only shows after the entire string is written, and it looks like I didn't hook the progress bar to the write process at all. Here is a sample output at the console (process took way more than 1s):

```
Printing: test:   0%|                                                             | 0/466073757 [00:00<?, ?it/s]466073757
Printing: test: 466073758it [00:01, 396677046.13it/s]
```

Is there a way to hook a progress bar to a `f.write()` process?

[another related question without answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716310/progress-bar-for-writing-text-to-a-file-how-much-time-it-takes-to-write-to-a-f)

**Edit:** In reply to comment for a working but *very* slow one-character-by-a-time code (not preferred):

```py
with open("./output/" + filename + ".txt", "w") as f:
    with tqdm(total=len(very_long_string)) as pbar:
        for char in very_long_string:
            f.write(char)
            pbar.update()
```

Comment: One possible way I can think of is to loop through the long string and write 1 character at a time, but obviously, while it works, it's excruciatingly slow (yeah I tried, and I immediately regretted) and not preferred.

Comment: Can you show that 1-char-at-a-time code?

Comment: @KellyBundy edited into question

Answer (score 1):

Like your 1-char-at-a-time, but instead a million at a time:

```
with open("./output/" + filename + ".txt", "w") as f:
    n = len(very_long_string)
    k = 10 ** 6
    with tqdm(total=n) as pbar:
        for i in range(0, n, k):
            chunk = very_long_string[i : i+k]
            f.write(chunk)
            pbar.update(len(chunk))
```

Comment: I'm worried if that breaking down of the string into chunks and passing it through f.write() multiple times would significantly slow down the process

Comment: @nayfaan Have you tried it?